On cutting tetrahedrons into mutually congruent pieces
Simple observations: A regular tetrahedron can be cut into 2 mutually congruent pieces (in 3 obvious ways which are all basically the same way, giving one and same pair of congruent pieces). The regular tet can be cut into 3 mutually congruent pieces (infinitely many sets of 3 resultant pieces) and into 6 pieces (1 obvious set of resultant pieces). It also allows congruent partition into 4 pieces (only one obvious set of pieces) and also into 12 pieces (infinitely many different sets of pieces based on first cutting into 4), 8 pieces (1 obvious set of pieces) and 24 pieces (1 obvious set).

Is there any tetrahedron (regular or otherwise) that can be cut into n mutually congruent connected pieces (no other constraint on the pieces, not even convexity) for any other value of n, say, 16 or 20...?


Do you know whether this is possible for triangles?

@M.Winter Isosceles triangle admits a filling by $kn^2$ congruent pieces for $k = 1, 2, 3, 6$. For any number which is a sum of 2 squares there's a right-angled triangle which can be cut into that many congruent triangles. As far as I know, the question whether there's a dissection of an isosceles triangle into 7 congruent pieces is still open (they cannot be triangles, which was proved by Beeson quite recently).

One simple note: the regular tetrahedron cannot be cut into any number of regular tetrahedra, and generically 'most' tetrahedra can't be cut into any number of tetrahedra congruent to the original, by non-zero Dehn invariant. (Of course, this does nothing to solve OP's question since this involves a strong additional constraint, but I figured it was worth noting)

One probably crucial difference between triangles and tets could be: although tets do not have an obvious partition into arbitrarily large number of congruent pieces (all triangles allow such partition for n any perfect square), there is in 3D (unlike on plane), more 'room' for non-convex solids to curve and wind around one another so one might just have some non-trivial congruent partitions of the tet for n values like perhaps 16 or 20.

I asked this question on Math StackExchange in the regular case three years ago here, along with some investigations into possible strategies for subdivision.

I think you underestimate the number of two-piece dissections of a regular tetrahedron into congruent pieces, Nandakumar. You can make a cut that includes one of the edges and bisects the edge opposite (in six ways that are all basically the same). Or, you can make a cut from one face through to any other face, bisecting two edges of each of the two faces (but not the edge the two faces have in common), another six ways that are all basically the same, but not the same as the previous dissection. See https://kubiyagames.com/products/2-piece-pyramid-brain-teaser-puzzle

This MSE question exhibits two non-regular tetrahedra which can be decomposed into 8 smaller copies congruent to themselves; this yields $8^n$ for any $n$.

This certainly is a partial answer - at least, I don't see a way to cut a regular tet into n pieces where n is any power of 8.  Remark: It is not clear to me if allowing non-convex pieces would help at all. thanks for the pointer to your question.

A family of so-called Hadwiger-Hill simplices in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_tetrahedron) can be cut into $m^d$ congruent simplices, all similar to the original simplex; that is, they are $m^d$-reptile.
See [2, Figure 1] for an illustration.
Maehara [1] described a construction of $d$ simplices that can be obtained from the right-angled Hadwiger-Hill simplex by repeatedly cutting in half. It can be shown that all these simplices are $(2m)^d$-reptile [3, Introduction]. As a consequence, the right-angled Hadwiger-Hill simplex can be cut into $2^km^d$ congruent pieces, for arbitrary values of $k,m$.
References:
[1] H. Maehara, Some replicating simplices other than Hill-simplices, Beitr. Algebra Geom. 55 (2) (2014), 429–432.
https://doi.org/10.1007/s13366-013-0152-8
[2] J. Matoušek and Z. Safernová, On the Nonexistence of k-reptile Tetrahedra. Discrete Comput Geom 46, 599–609 (2011).
https://doi.org/10.1007/s00454-011-9334-z
[3] J. Kynčl and Z. Patáková, On the nonexistence of k-reptile simplices in R^3 and R^4 (with Z. Patakova), The Electronic Journal of Combinatorics 24 (2017), Issue 3, P3.1, 44 pp.
https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v24i3p1
